# Import paths - the right way?

Tags: python, path, python-import

I know there are A LOT of similar or the same questions, but i still cannot understand / find the right way for me to work with modules. Python is my favorite language, and i like everything in it except working with imports: recursive imports (when you try to reference a name that is not yet there), import paths, etc.

So, I have this kind of a project structure:

```
my_project/
    package1/
        __init__.py
        module1
        module2
    package2/
        __init__.py
        module1
        module2
```

`Package1` may be used a standalone unit, but is also expected to be imported by `package2`.
What am i doing now, is that, for example, in `package1.module1` i write `from package1 import module2`, i.e. using full path to imported module. I do this because if i use `import module2` -- this will not work when the module will be imported from another package (`package2`). I also cannot use `from . import module2` -- this will not work when running `module1` directly.

OK, so for `from package1 import module2` in `package1.module1` to work in both cases (when running directly `package1.module1` and when importing it from `package2`) i add these lines at the beginning of `package1.module1`:

```
import os, sys
currDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
rootDir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(currDir, '..'))
if rootDir not in sys.path: # add parent dir to paths
    sys.path.append(rootDir)
```

For me this works, but i feel this is not pythonic. Am i doing something wrong?

Should i, instead, always run `package1.module1` from project root? If so, this makes inconvenient to run it from an IDE -- i need somehow to set paths in it.

UPDATE: I tried to add a file `root.pth` to `package1` dir with contents of `..`. But it didn't work -- i guess it's intended for something else.

**CONCLUSIONS:**

1. Always use absolute imports: `import package1.module1`
2. Add a bootstrapper to the root folder to start some of the modules as a standalone script. This solves running the script form an IDE and is a pythonic approach.

On 4/22/07, Brett Cannon wrote:

> This PEP is to change the `if __name__ == "__main__": ...` idiom to
>   `if __name__ == sys.main: ...`  so that you at least have a chance
>   to execute module in a package that use relative imports.
>
> Ran this PEP past python-ideas.  Stopped the discussion there when too
>   many new ideas were being proposed.  =)  I have listed all of them in
>   the Rejected Ideas section, although if overwhelming support for one
>   comes forward the PEP can shift to one of them.

I'm -1 on this and on any other proposed twiddlings of the `__main__`
machinery. The only use case seems to be running scripts that happen
to be living inside a module's directory, which I've always seen as an
antipattern. To make me change my mind you'd have to convince me that
it isn't.

--[Guido van Rossum](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-April/006793.html)

Comment: This comment has nothing to do with imports, but the convention in python for variable names is `word_secondword` instead of `wordSecondword`

Comment: @Josh Smeaton, Well, i work a lot with scrapy, and sometimes with PyQt4, both of them are using camelCase, so i also decided to use it

Comment: to be picky, I just checked the scrapy docs, and they use snake_case too. http://doc.scrapy.org/0.10/topics/spiders.html. The exception is ClassNames. variables_are_snake_though. I'll leave it be though :P

Comment: I'm fairly new to python, can you explain what you mean by "bootstrapper"? Is that the __init__.py in the root with some import statements?

Comment: no, it's a file that imports needed submodules from the package to start the app. it's an entry point. before my entry point was inside the package, now it's one level up. i called it `start_package1.py`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

What is the entry point for your program? Usually the entry point for a program will be at the root of the project. Since it is at the root, all the modules within the root will be importable, provided there is an `__init__.py` file in them.

So, using your example:

```
my_project/
    main.py
    package1/
        __init__.py
        module1
        module2
    package2/
        __init__.py
        module1
        module2
```

`main.py` would be the entry point for your program. Because the file that is executed as main is automatically put on the PYTHONPATH, both `package1` and `package2` are available from the top level import.

```
# in main.py
from package1.module1 import *
from package1.module2 import *

# in package1.module1
import module2
from package2.module1 import *

# in package2.module1 import *
import module2
from package1.module1 import *
```

Note that in the above, package1 and package2 depend on each other. That should never be the case. But this is just an example of being able to import from anywhere.

`main.py` doesn't have to be anything fancy either. It can be very simple:

```
# main.py

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from package1.module1 import SomeClass
    SomeClass().start()
```

The point I'm trying to make, is that if a module needs to be accessible by other modules, that module should be available as a top level import. A module should not attempt to put itself as a top level import (directly on the PYTHONPATH).

It should be the responsibility of the **project** for ensuring that all imports can be satisfied if the module is included directly in the project. There are two ways to do this. The first is by creating a bootstrapper file such as `main.py` in the project folder. The other, is by creating a file that adds all relevant paths to PYTHONPATH, that is loaded by any entry points that may exist.

For example:

```
# setup.py
import sys

def load():
    paths = ['/path1/','/path2/','/path3/']
    for p in path:
        sys.path.insert(0, p)

# entrypoint.py
from setup import load
load()
# continue with program
```

The main thing to take away, is that a module is **not** supposed to put itself on the path. The path should be determined automatically by the entry point into the program, or defined explicitly by a setup script that knows where all the relevant modules are.

Comment: i have two entry points. sometimes i use `package1` as standalone program. sometimes `package1` is imported from another entry point.

Comment: My suggestion is to use a bootstrapper file, such as main.py that I mentioned in my answer. Don't start your program from any where other than the root of the project. The alternative is a bootstrapper elsewhere in the project, which adds all the necessary modules to `sys.path`. If you have a module that can be used by others, it's important that something ELSE is responsible for making sure that module is available as a top level import.

Comment: OK. I think that is the answer i was looking for - to make a bootstrapper. So i will add a py file at the root dir which will start package1 when it is needed as standalone.

Answer (score 6):

I generally create each package as an installable package (ie, create a setup.py file), and then install them into a virtualenv just for this project, using pip.

You can even install the using pip -e if they are still under development.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 5 years late here.. but just do `export PYTHONPATH=/path1:/path2:` (notice trailing ":") - this way your working directory (from which you run python) will be in the path.

Comment: This might work, but will spoil the modules -- the same module can be imported twice with different  `__name__`s. And generally it's a bad idea to change `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH` for cases like this.

Comment: I wish I understood your answer better. For me, anything with `sys.path` modified in the code feels non-pythonic. If there is one entry point everything is simple, but for development - you need to run arbitrary modules at an arbitrary time! And the only way to achieve it (at least the only way that worked for me), is to modify "PYTHONPATH" of the project in your IDE, that way you can do absolute imports from non-main entry point.

Comment: See [this](http://blindvic.blogspot.com/2012/04/guido-views-running-scripts-within.html)

Comment: Well, that is a somewhat different question. The question is: "How to run scripts withing package", and your answer is "Don't run scripts within package!!". Perhaps for the final version, this is a poor practice, but for development, it is quite useful! There are currently two options - `sys.path` on the code level, and `PYTHONPATH` on the system level. Please, explain your solution to the problem of running modules within a package!

Comment: My question was not only about development, but also about production. The solution is in the accepted answer: make a bootstrap/entry point in the top level directory, which will import the needed module and call the worker function from it

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.