# Relative import inside flat package

Tags: python, package

I have a package of the following form:

```
$ ls folder
entry_point.py  hello.py  __init__.py  utils.py
```

This is a package, and I can treat it as such:

```
$ python2.7
>>> import folder.utils
>>>
```

I want to use relative imports between these Python modules.

```
$ cat folder/entry_point.py 
from hello import say_hello

if __name__ == "__main__":
    say_hello()
$ cat folder/hello.py 
from .utils import say

def say_hello():
    say()
$ cat folder/utils.py
def say():
    print "hello world"
```

I know I can't use relative imports at the entry point, where I call the interpreter. However, I still get `ImportError` from my imported files:

```
$ python2.7 folder/entry_point.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "folder/entry_point.py", line 1, in <module>
    from hello import say_hello
  File "/tmp/folder/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .utils import say
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

This is rather counterintuitive, it is a package, it's just not treated as one due to entry_point.py having `__name__` set to `__main__` (in line with PEP 328).

I'm surprised that hello.py has a `__name__` of `hello` rather than `folder.hello`. This stops me using relative imports in hello.py.

How do I use relative imports in this package? Am I forced to move hello.py and utils.py to a libs subpackage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `folder` to be a module inside a bigger project and you want to be able to run `entry_point.py` for using your `folder` module - move `entry_point.py` one level up:

```
from folder.hello import say_hello

if __name__ == "__main__":
    say_hello()
```

[Import paths - the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465549/import-paths-the-right-way)

Comment: Excellent, thanks. It turns out `__name__` is mutable so it would be possible to do `__name__ = 'folder.hello'`. Your solution is the most elegant available though.