# Getting `Top `level package` error when importing module in `python3`

Tags: python

I am having directory structure as

```
-Practice
 -Connect
    -connect.py -> having function abc
    -__init__.py
 -Pytest
    -__init__.py
    -file.py
```

`file.1 contents`

```
from ..connect.connect import abc
abc()
```

Getting error as

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

I can use import from parent directory as

```
from connect.connect import abc
abc()
```

This is working. Need to know why relative import is not working

As people suggested i have added **init**.py in Practice directory and still getting same error

Comment: Add `__init__.py` file in `Practice` directory

Comment: @warvariuc: I added __init__.py in Practice directory and not working

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465549/import-paths-the-right-way
I suspect that you are trying to run/import `file.py` being inside `Pytest` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `__init__.py` inside the top level `Practice` folder, so Python knows that it's supposed to be a package in its own right, as opposed to a random folder that happens to contain two packages.

Comment: I added __init__.py file in practice folder but still getting same results

Answer (score 0):

You need an __init__.py in your Practice directory too. Otherwise, Pytest and Connect are separate toplevel packages and not sibling subpackages of the Practice package. Hence the error you're getting.

Comment: I added __init__.py file in practice folder but still getting same results

Comment: is the Practice directory on the PYTHONPATH ?

Comment: No, Practice is not in PythonPath